# OpenMP - Mac M1 gcc and libomp not working

Tags: c++, c, gcc, openmp, apple-m1

I need to setup OpenMP for my coursework and I am still new to C & C++

So far I have been using Apple's built in Clang and GCC compilers,

I assumed this would have support for OpenMP out of the box.

I have read a few answers here but they are either incomplete or I find them very confusing

I installed llvm, but Im not sure what's the point of this,

I followed the instructions and added it to my path but it still doesn't make a difference.

What's the best way to setup C/C++ environment on Mac M1, that has support for OpenMP?

Here is the basic program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

#define THREADS 8
int main()
{
    int tid, nthreads;

    omp_set_num_threads(THREADS);

    // start of parallel section
    // Fork a team of threads with each thread having a private tid variable
    #pragma omp parallel private(tid)
    {
        tid=omp_get_thread_num();
        printf("Hello world from thread %d\n", tid);
        /* Only master thread does this */
        if (tid == 0) {
            nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();
            printf("Number of threads = %d\n", nthreads);
        }


    }//end of parallel section
    // All threads join master thread and terminate


    return 0;
}  // end main()
```

[image: I added that to the path variable and checked .zshrc]

I have also done:

```
brew install libomp
```

Which works fine, but how am I supposed to get the OpenMP in the file to work?
There doesn't seem to be any further details anywhere

I have watched this video, I assume She is speaking Spanish, although I can't understand what is being said, I followed it and I am not getting the new gcc already installed: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=54S0tw0UrUg

I have downloaded gcc but it is still showing the same apple clang:

```
gcc -v
Apple clang version 13.1.6 (clang-1316.0.21.2.5)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin21.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

I have managed to get the gcc installed as well as libomp

When I ran the program I got this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_omp_get_num_threads", referenced from:
      _main in ccK3z6BU.o
  "_omp_get_thread_num", referenced from:
      _main in ccK3z6BU.o
  "_omp_set_num_threads", referenced from:
      _main in ccK3z6BU.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: When you installed GCC, did you use `brew install gcc`? If so, you should run `brew info gcc` and read the usage instructions. You should also run `brew ls gcc` to see exactly where it installed the `gcc` compiler binary and then be sure to use its full path. Get used to running `type gcc` to see exactly what will be run if you enter `gcc` without a path like you did.

Comment: If `type gcc` tells you a path starting with `/usr/bin` or `/Applications` you are still running Apple-supplied compilers, not **homebrew** ones which are normally in `/usr/local/bin` or `/opt`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for this, It is working now. I can use both headers omp.h as well as the full path to the libomp installed, I was about to close the question

Comment: I just installed gcc yes and now it works, but I have to use gcc-11. I may need to create an alias. Is it possible to do this dynamically so that as the version updates, I can update it automatically ?

Comment: You could make an alias. Personally I hate them as they may not exist in non-login shells, in `cron`, if Apple changes from `bash` to `zsh` (oh, they did already) and so on. The version has only got to 11 in the last 40 years, so it doesn't change often and if you build with Makefiles it's simple to change. YMMV.

Comment: That's very helpful thanks. Just one last question if I may, I notice on my Mac, there is a separate compiler for C & C++. Will I have to download something different to get this to work on C++ which is what I will eventually use

Comment: If you installed GCC with **homebrew** you will have got `g++-11` already for compiling C++ programs.

Answer (score 1):

Had similar issues after installing with brew on MacBook Air with M1 chip.
Running the g++ installed with homebrew instead of default one solved it for me.

- brew ls gcc

The full path for g++ was

- /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/12.2.0/bin/g++-12

Now I can compile with -fopenmp like this:

- /opt/homebrew/Cellar/gcc/12.2.0/bin/g++-12 -fopenmp pragma_test.cpp

Sample program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libomp/15.0.6/include/omp.h"

int main() {
    #pragma omp parallel
    printf("Hello from thread %d, nthreads %d\n", omp_get_thread_num(), omp_get_num_threads());
}
```

And it works as it should:

```
Hello from thread 1, nthreads 8
Hello from thread 6, nthreads 8
Hello from thread 2, nthreads 8
Hello from thread 5, nthreads 8
Hello from thread 0, nthreads 8
Hello from thread 4, nthreads 8
Hello from thread 3, nthreads 8
Hello from thread 7, nthreads 8
```